# Clojure koans destructuring example

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am currently looking at this online [clojure koan](http://clojurescriptkoans.com/#destructuring/7) related to destructuring 
arguments but unable to pass it

The koan looks like as follow:

Given data:

```
(def test-address
  {:street-address "123 Test Lane"
   :city "Testerville"
   :state "TX"})
```

we have

```
(= "Test Testerson, 123 Test Lane, Testerville, TX" 
     (  ----missing part-----       ["Test" "Testerson"] test-address))
```

One of my solutions was:

```
 (= "Test Testerson, 123 Test Lane, Testerville, TX" 
     ( apply 
        (fn[ a & more ] 
          ( let [ x (reduce str (interpose " " a))  
                  y (reduce str (interpose ", " (vals more) ))]  
                  (str x ", " y)))  ["Test" "Testerson"] test-address))
```

This works in repl but not on given site. So my question is, is there a better solution ? I am not sure if above example set to look for better or specific  solution .

Comment: one thing you have to consider is that the order of the values of `test-address` in the equation you'r trying to solve is different from the order of the key-value pairs as `test-address` was defined. `vals` give you the values in the same order as the kv paires were `def`ined, so you have to change this order.

Comment: This is actually the ONLY problem in your code. You just have to put your `(vals more)` inside something like `(reverse (sort-by count (vals more)))` (as here the order of `more` is equal with the dimension of its strings) and it will work fine. I also have added this little correction below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason your code could have failed is because the map keys are not ordered. `(vals more)` can and most likely will give differently ordered sequences in different versions of clojure.

A solution you might try instead is,

```
((fn 
   [[f-name l-name] {:keys [street-address city state]}] 
     (format "%s %s, %s, %s, %s" f-name, l-name, street-address, city, state)) 
     ["Test" "Testerson"] {:street-address "123 Test Lane", :city "Testerville", :state "TX"})
```

EDIT: clojurescript doesn't have `format` implemented [1]. You could replace the entire `format` form with the following `str` form,

```
(str f-name " " l-name ", " street-address ", " city ", " state)
```

I have tried it and it works.

[1] - http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-324

Comment: Your solution also works in `REPL` but not in given site, probably some issue with validation . However, thanks for `format` function and destructuring arguments properly :)

Comment: @sakhunzai, updated the answer. It works with the site as well. FWIW, the site is clojurescript koans and not clojure koans. There are slight incompatibilities.

Comment: thanks again for clarifying the difference and solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with the small correction:

```
(= "Test Testerson, 123 Test Lane, Testerville, TX" 
    (apply 
    (fn [a & more] 
      (let [x (reduce str (interpose " " a))  
            y (reduce str (interpose ", " (reverse (sort-by count (vals more)))))]  
        (str x ", " y)))
    ["Test" "Testerson"] test-address)
 )

=> ;true
```

Comment: thanks Amir but why I should need to apply three more function i.e sort and reverse. What makes my function fail ?

Comment: Call `(vals test-address)` and compare the order of the values with their order in the first line of the test ("123 Test Lane, Testerville, TX"). The `vals` function gives you them in another order as they have been asked in the test, and thats why your code has failed to pass the test.

Answer (score 0):

This works on both the [Koan](http://clojurescriptkoans.com/#destructuring/7) website and in the repl:

```
(fn [x m] 
    (clojure.string/join ", " 
      (cons (clojure.string/join " " x) 
        (reverse (sort-by count (vals m)))
      )
    )
 )
```

It `cons`es the two new strings `["Test" "Testerson"]` `join`ed together, to the values of the `test-address` and keeps the resulting string in the same order as the answer using `sort-by` and `reverse`.